# Sacar una consulta sql

Tags: mysql, sql

Hola buenos dias y espero vuestra ayuda. Necesito sacar de la tabla

restaurante:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y de la tabla
usuario:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

todos aquellos restaurantes que no pertenezcan a un usuario en este caso es el 3 ( de nombre restaurante vacio), porque como podréis comprobar en la tabla usuario los id_restaurante de cada usuario es o 1 o 2.

Yo que hace tiempo que toco poco las consultas he hecho esto pero no me lo saca:

```
select r.id, r.nombre, r.direccion, r.ciudad, r.provincia, r.cp, r.cif, r.imagen_url, r.horario 

from restaurante r inner join usuario u on u.id_restaurante = r.id

where u.id_restaurante != r.id
group by r.id
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En tu consulta `INNER JOIN` no te saldrán aquellos elementos que no tengan una relación establecida entre ambas tablas.

Debes usar [`LEFT JOIN` o `RIGHT JOIN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html) para que liste todos los registros de una de las dos tablas (derecha o izquierda) independientemente de si existe alguno relacionado en la otra tabla.

Al usar una relación de este tipo los elementos no existentes de la otra tabla aparecerán como valores `NULL`, por lo que podemos buscar cualquier campo (yo he elegido `u.id`, pero podría haber sido otro que no pueda tener valor `NULL`, como `u.id_restaurante`) de esa tabla que sea `NULL`, por ejemplo:

```
SELECT r.*
FROM restaurante r
LEFT JOIN
  usuario u
  ON u.id_restaurante = r.id
WHERE u.id IS NULL
```

Comment: muchisimas gracias, solucionado y me has ayudado a recordar consultas, ahora caigo!!

Comment: De nada, un placer. Te he votado positiva la pregunta para que superes los 15 puntos de reputación :) agradecería que si te ayudó mi respuesta la marcaras como correcta y/o la votaras positivamente. Gracias.